# How do you convert a time "duration" from a string value into an integer?

Tags: php, string, time, duration

I have a bunch of string values that represent an interval in time like this:

`'1 hour'`, `'1.5 hours'`, `'30 minutes'`, etc...

I'd like to convert all of these values into a count of minutes, so the above would become respectively:

`60`, `90`, `30`

I've been messing around with `Carbon\Carbon` and PHP's `strtotime()` function, but I can't figure out how I'd do this. It's probably really simple?

Comment: parse it, change it, load it (using [the `DateInterval` class](http://php.net/dateinterval)), or change the data you're working with to valid interval formats, and just use `DateInterval` instances to begin with

Comment: 1 hour equals 60 mins, `1x60=60` and `1.5x60=90` 30 minutes is minutes so parse as double and multiply by 60

Comment: @Bsienn: you can't multiply by 60 without knowing what the rest of the string means (seconds, days minutes, hours...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '1 hour';
$int1 = strtotime("+".$str)- strtotime("now");
```

Here `$int1` will return time in seconds. here it will return `3600`. And this wont handle fractions like `1.5 hours` etc.